# Defining items of an object inside the initialize function

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I am trying to create items inside a component as it gets initialized, with a function.

Consider the following:

```
Ext.define('mobi.form.Login',{
    extend:'Ext.form.Panel',
    config:{    
        items: [{
        xtype: 'textfield',
        name: 'Name',
        label: 'Name'
        }]
});
Ext.application({
    viewport: {
        layout:'fit'        
    },
    launch: function(){
        Ext.Viewport.add(Ext.create('mobi.form.Login'));
    }
})
```

I am trying to get The `mobi.form.login` to generate its config from a function that runs on `initialize` ( or whatever I can use to over write the config I specify ).

I know Sencha touch 2 has the `constructor`, and `initialize` function, but both of them seem to have  `arguments=[]` ( eg an empty array )

This is more or less how it would look if I was doing it in ExtJS 4.x:

```
Ext.define('mobi.form.Login',{
    extend:'Ext.form.Panel',
    initComponent:function(config){
        config=Ext.apply({}.config,{});//make sure config exists    
        config.items= [{
            xtype: 'textfield',
            name: 'Name',
            label: 'Name'
        }]
    Ext.apply(this, config);
    this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

Comment: If you really wanted to do this, you would do it in the `constructor`. It gets the config you pass to Ext.create() just link `initComponent`, so you could use the exact same code you are using above. But the question is; why would you want to do this? We wanted to make the config system as flexible as possible with 2.x, so we introduced that `config` block so you don't need initComponent anymore. In what situation can you not use use `config`?

Comment: Constructor has no arguments though, which is odd? The config inside Ext.define doesn't allow you to refer to `this` as the scope of a panel, meaning you have to define a controller just to do this.reset() on a form for example. Mitchell Simoens has something similar to what I am trying to do in his grid extensions ( I think ). https://github.com/mitchellsimoens/Ext.ux.touch.grid/blob/master/Ext.ux.touch.grid/View.js but none of what he is doing can be found in the docs ( unless I am blind ).

Comment: Another example off the top of my head would be to define a form that does an ajax call to get its config on init ( which is fun for forms ).

Comment: Since you did technically point me in the right direction, your welcome to claim the bounty on this. The fact that the `config` isn't passed to the constructor threw me off.

Comment: I added a proper answer. `constructor` should pass the arguments; I added an example and tested it and it worked fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you ever wanted to do this, you could use `constructor` or `initialize`.

Constructor you would use for synchronous logic which will be fast and you want to happen before the component is initialized. You can access the configuration through the constructors first argument:

```
Ext.define('MyComponent', {
    extend: 'Ext.Component',

    constructor: function(config) {
        console.log(config);

        this.callParent([config]);
    }
});

Ext.application({
    launch: function(){
        Ext.create('MyComponent', { test: 1 })

        // Will log out:
        // {
        //     test: 1
        // }
    }
});
```

Remember you will *always* need to `callParent` with the `config`/`arguments` within constructor.

In any other situation, you should use `initialize` which is called **after** all the config's have been... initialized. :) We use this a lot internally for adding listeners.

```
initialize: function() {
    this.on({
        ...
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you don't need to call initialize manually it is already done by constructor and when calling this function you can access items data using this.items and create panel items there

```
Ext.define('mobi.form.Login',{
    extend:'Ext.form.Panel',
    config: {
        items: []
    },

    initialize : function()
    {
        this.items = [Ext.create({
             xtype: 'textfield',
             name: 'Name',
             label: 'Name'
        })];

        this.callParent();
    }
});

Ext.application({
    viewport: {
        layout:'fit'        
    },
    launch: function(){
        Ext.Viewport.add(Ext.create('mobi.form.Login'));
    }
})
```

Comment: @Alex can you tell me is this what you want or i am understanding it wrong?

Comment: Kind of. See rdougans answer for exactly what I wanted :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
Ext.apply(this, {
    items: [
 .... 
    ]
});
```

Comment: Oops, this was missing from my ExtJS example as well. Inside which function should I be calling that though? Simply merging an object config into `this` wont exactly do much if its already configured eveything.

Comment: Then it should work. You're missing some closing braket in your sample, but I guess it's a typo. Did you try to log what's inside items array after you do Ext.apply and before calling parent?

Comment: Hmm, maybe the question itself is unclear, the pseudo code that I do at the bottom, is what I would like to reproduce in the touch framework, as the initComponent function doesnt exist in Sencha touch to my knowledge, so that would be working code ( minus errors and stuff i forgot ( que Ext.apply ). I'm looking for the function I can use to do that, and hopefully an example :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something similar to this?  I'm just passing a config object to Ext.create, though I can't test it right now.  See  http://docs.sencha.com/touch/1-1/#!/api/Ext-method-create

```
Ext.Viewport.add(Ext.create(
    {
        xtype: 'mobi.form.Login',
        items: [ /*A list of items*/ ]
    }
));
```

You could stick this snippet in its own function as well, one that takes in items as a parameter.  Hope this solves your problem!